# Увеличительный суффикс "л"

Tags: этимология, морфология, суффиксы

В описании происхождения слова "орёл" в словаре Фасмера написано, что тут есть вставка "л" (имеется в виду не только русский язык, но и многие другие европейские):

> Редкий формант -ьlъ является увеличительным

А в каких ещё русских словах встречается этот увеличительный суффикс? Кроме "хамло" (*хам* -> *хамло*, хотя может быть и *хам* -> *хамить* -> *хамло*, тогда это не тот случай) и одного матерного слова, ничего не могу вспомнить.

Answer (score 1):

Суффикс Л используется для образования существительных общего рода со значением лица, которое обычно или постоянно выполняет действия, названные мотивирующим глаголом: кутила, зубрила, меняла, вышибала, громила, чудила.

Слово хамло,  скорее всего, также образовано от глагола "хамить".

У Черных формант -ьlъ  в слове "орел" назван о-с. суффиксом (расширителем), но о его увеличительном значении там не говорится.

Answer (score 0):

Ну... Возможно, ещё вот это:

http://mat.slovaronline.com/К/КО/1603-KOBEL